# How to receive multipart request in Spring App

Tags: java, json, spring, http, multipartform-data

I've seen many sources and also few questions on SO but didn't find solution.

I want to send to my Spring app POST/PUT-requests that contain JSON-object `Car` and attached file.

For the moment I have a `CarController` which correctly works with JSON-objects

```
@PutMapping("/{id}/update")
public void updateCar(@PathVariable(value = "id") Long carId, @Validated @RequestBody Car car) throws ResourceNotFoundException {
    // I can work with received car
}
```

I also have a `FileController` which correctly works with `file`

```
@PostMapping("/upload")
public void uploadFiles(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) throws IOException {
    // I can work with received file
}
```

But how should my method look like to be able to work with both `car` and `file`? This code doesn't provide me any of `car` or `file`.

```
@PutMapping("/{id}/update")
public void updateCar(@PathVariable(value = "id") Long carId, @Validated @RequestBody Car car, @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) throws ResourceNotFoundException, IOException {
    // can not work neither with car nor with file
}
```

Separate controllers work well during test from Postman. But when I try third code I got these results:
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, I [agree with Vladimir](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70116219/592355); `multipart/form-data`, `@RequestPart`s instead of body & param:

```
@PutMapping(value = "/{id}/update", consumes = {MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE})
public void updateCar(@PathVariable(value = "id") Long carId,
        @RequestPart("car") Car car, 
        @RequestPart("file") MultipartFile file) {
   ...
```

Then in Postman:

[image: Postman Screenshot]

- use Body>form-data
- when issues:

  - display `Content-Type` column.
  - set `Content-Type` per part.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `consumes = { MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE }` field of `@RequestMapping` annotation and `@RequestPart` annotation for method parameters:

```
ResponseEntity<> foo(@RequestPart ParType value, @RequestPart MultipartFile anotherChoice) {
...
```

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing wrong with your code and it could work as it is.

You could eventually improve its readability by using @RequestPart instead of @RequestParam and @RequestBody when it's a multipart request.

You can find more details about multipart requests in this article [https://www.baeldung.com/sprint-boot-multipart-requests](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vZOCr.png)

Most importantly, to make it work/ or to test in the correct way:

When using postman for multipart requests, you have to define the content type of each RequestPart.

It's a hidden column in the form-data screen, that you can show as follows:
[image]

Check the box "Content-Type" and the new column will appear:
[image]

And finally, define the content type of each part.