# sending post request with axios and formData, Content-Type 'application/octet-stream' is not supported

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, http, axios, multipartform-data

This react component:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ReactQuill from "react-quill";
import "react-quill/dist/quill.snow.css";
import { useDropzone } from "react-dropzone";
import axios from "axios";

function Wysiwyg() {
  const [image, setImage] = useState(null);
  const [title, setTitle] = useState("");
  const [description, setDescription] = useState("");
  const [price, setPrice] = useState("");

  const handleImageDrop = (acceptedFiles) => {
    setImage(acceptedFiles[0]);
  };

  const handleTitleChange = (e) => {
    setTitle(e.target.value);
  };

  const handleDescriptionChange = (value) => {
    setDescription(value);
  };

  const handlePriceChange = (e) => {
    setPrice(e.target.value);
  };

  const handleSave = () => {
    console.log("Product saved:", { image, title, description, price });
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('title', title);
    formData.append('description', description);
    formData.append('price', price);
    formData.append('image', image);

    axios.post("http://localhost:8080/save-product", formData, {
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
      },
    });
  };

  const { getRootProps, getInputProps } = useDropzone({
    accept: "image/*",
    onDrop: handleImageDrop,
  });

  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Edit Product</h2>
      <div>
        <label htmlFor="image">Image:</label>
        <div {...getRootProps()} style={dropzoneStyles}>
          <input {...getInputProps()} />
          {image ? (
            <img
              src={URL.createObjectURL(image)}
              alt="Product"
              style={{ width: "100%" }}
            />
          ) : (
            <p>Drag 'n' drop an image here, or click to select one</p>
          )}
        </div>
      </div>
      <div>
        <label htmlFor="title">Title:</label>
        <input
          type="text"
          id="title"
          value={title}
          onChange={handleTitleChange}
        />
      </div>
      <div>
        <label htmlFor="description">Description:</label>
        <ReactQuill
          value={description}
          onChange={handleDescriptionChange}
          modules={quillModules}
          formats={quillFormats}
        />
      </div>
      <div>
        <label htmlFor="price">Price:</label>
        <input
          type="number"
          id="price"
          value={price}
          onChange={handlePriceChange}
        />
      </div>
      <button onClick={handleSave}>Save</button>
    </div>
  );
}

const dropzoneStyles = {
  border: "2px dashed #ccc",
  borderRadius: "4px",
  padding: "20px",
  textAlign: "center",
  cursor: "pointer",
  margin: "10px 0",
};

const quillModules = {
  toolbar: [
    [{ header: [1, 2, false] }],
    ["bold", "italic", "underline", "strike", "blockquote"],
    [{ list: "ordered" }, { list: "bullet" }],
    ["link", "image"],
    ["clean"],
  ],
};

const quillFormats = [
  "header",
  "bold",
  "italic",
  "underline",
  "strike",
  "blockquote",
  "list",
  "bullet",
  "link",
  "image",
];

export default Wysiwyg;
```

is sending multipart (not JSON) data to spring server. It is doing so in handleSave function:

```
const handleSave = () => {
    console.log("Product saved:", { image, title, description, price });
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('title', title);
    formData.append('description', description);
    formData.append('price', price);
    formData.append('image', image);

    axios.post("http://localhost:8080/save-product", formData, {
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
      },
    });
  };
```

Now spring boot controller handling those data:

```
@RestController
public class ProductController {
    @PostMapping("/save-product")
    public ResponseEntity<String> saveProduct(
            @RequestPart("title") String title,
            @RequestPart("description") String description,
            @RequestPart("price") BigDecimal price,
            @RequestPart("image") MultipartFile image
    ) {
        Path imagePath = Path.of(System.getProperty("user.dir"), "images");
        try {
            if (!Files.exists(imagePath)) {
                Files.createDirectories(imagePath);
            }
            image.transferTo(imagePath.resolve(image.getOriginalFilename()));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        System.out.println("Title: " + title);
        System.out.println("Description: " + description);
        System.out.println("Price: " + price);
        System.out.println("Image Original Filename: " + image.getOriginalFilename());
        return ResponseEntity.ok("Product saved successfully");
    }
}
```

But when the request is sent (the Save button is clicked), I got:

```
Resolved [org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content-Type 'application/octet-stream' is not supported]
```

But in the axios there is specificially set the header to

```
headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
      },
```

so whats wrong?

Comment: the "cool thing" about multipart: each part (can have &) has custom content type ...but how to tell it to axios?? .... https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestPart.html .... vs.(!) https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestParam.html ...

Comment: "please try" `@RequestParam` (in favor to (some-all) `@RequestPart`s) ...or (client-sided) set the appropriate content type *per* part.

Comment: @xerx593 what? Which arguments should be RequestParam and why? when the content-type is multipart, it all should be requestpart right?

Comment: no, when you use RequestPart (which is ok), you should submit (on client side..if you can) title, description, price -> `text/plain`(!?;)  and the image with the according mime type (gif/jpeg/...) (!?) ..in postman (please test), it could look [like so](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70116583/592355).... i don't know how it works in react.js ;( https://www.google.com/search?q=reactjs+multipart+with+multiple+part+content+types ...

Comment: yes, it worked when changed to requestparam. But then I dont really see the use case of requestpart when even if the axios post as `multipart/form-data` (specified in headers key of config object of the axios.post) I still use requestparam. When to use requestpart then?

Comment: it worked probably due to the notes in the linked javadocs ... :) They (param|part) are equals with subtle "conversion differences"

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30194096/592355) can help to understand the structure of a multipart request, as setting multiple (part-specific) content types ..on the client side.

Comment: @xerx593 the link is more general http mutlipart description. Put my question in other way: what is a **specific** use case in spring boot where one would opt to use requestpart instead of requestparam?

Comment: RequestPart is strictly tied to "multipart/form-data", RequestParam allows more flexible clients.... (I give you links for you to study, not for me to show off;)  ....it would be good to know which part raises the mentioned error message... intensively reading the javadoc, I have one special suspicion: it should be the `@RequestPart("price") BigDecimal price` to blame...(?) ..please try (all RequestPart) and `String price`.

Comment: "The main difference is that when the method argument is *not a String or raw MultipartFile / Part*, `@RequestParam` relies on "(server!) blahblah" ... while `RequestPart` relies on "(request!+server (other)) blahblah""